# Speex decoded frame is not as the original frame

Tags: c, compression, frame, encode, speex

i need your help in determining the problem in the following sample code (taken from speex manual) for fixed point encoding.
i tested encoding a 160 sample frame and then decoding it back But The problem is that the decoded frame is totally different from the original frame(see output below in a comment).What is the possible reason for this?.thanks for any help

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include"intel16.h"
#include <speex/speex.h>
#define FRAME_SIZE 160
#define MAX_NB_BYTES 25

SpeexBits bits;
void *enc_state;
int quality=4;      
int nbBytes;

int byte_ptr;

int frame_size;

short frame[FRAME_SIZE]; 

char outBuffer[20];
SpeexBits decBits;

void *dec_state;

short decFrame[FRAME_SIZE];

int z=0;

int frame_size;

int main (int argc,char **argv)
{
for( z=0;z<160;z++)
    {
    frame[z]=intel_theme[z];  //array of short from "intel16" header file
    }
 printf("\n =================================== \n");

 for( z=0;z<160;z++)
    {
        printf("%i",frame[z]);
    printf ("  ");
        }
     speex_bits_init(&bits);

     enc_state = speex_encoder_init(&speex_nb_mode);



    speex_encoder_ctl(enc_state,SPEEX_GET_FRAME_SIZE,&frame_size);

     speex_encoder_ctl(enc_state,SPEEX_SET_QUALITY,&quality);

     speex_bits_reset(&bits);

      speex_encode_int(enc_state, frame, &bits);     
           // encoding from frame to &bits
     nbBytes = speex_bits_write(&bits, outBuffer, MAX_NB_BYTES); 
         //writing from &bits to outBuffer
//----------------------------------------------------    
     speex_bits_destroy(&bits);

     speex_encoder_destroy(enc_state);  

     printf("\n outBuffer: ");

      for(z=0;z<20;z++)
   {
   printf("%c",outBuffer[z]);
   }
   printf("\n \n");

//-----------DECODING-------------------
speex_bits_init(&decBits);
dec_state=speex_decoder_init(&speex_nb_mode);
speex_decoder_ctl(dec_state, SPEEX_GET_FRAME_SIZE, &frame_size);


speex_bits_read_from(&decBits,outBuffer,nbBytes);
speex_decode_int(dec_state,&decBits,decFrame);
//----------------------------------------------------
printf("\n BUFFER DECODED BACK \n");

for(z=0;z<160;z++)
{
printf("%i",decFrame[z]);
printf ("  ");
}

speex_bits_destroy(&decBits);
speex_decoder_destroy(dec_state);
/*==========END OF DECODING==============*/
printf("\n nbBytes: ");
printf("%i",nbBytes);
printf("\n frame_size= ");
printf("%i",frame_size);
printf ("\n");
//-----------------
printf("end of run!");

return 0;
}
```

Comment: OUTPUT:
//the original frame
1  -512  16384  512  -768  -2048  -1280  256  -1024  12288  0  8192  253  256  -768  12288  0  -16  -768  -512  -1  0  -512  -768  -1536  -512  -512  -768  16384  0  8192  -512  16384  512  -768  -2048  -1280  256  -1024  12288  0  8192  253  256  -768  12288  0  -16  -768  -512  -1  0  -512  -768  -1536  -512  -512  -768  16384  0  8192  -512  16384  512  -768  -2048  -1280  256  -1024  12288  0  8192  253  256  -768  12288  0  -16  -768  -512  -1  0  -512  -768  -1536  -512  -512  -768  -4136

Comment: //the decoded frame .totally different
 BUFFER DECODED BACK
0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  2838  -3982  4801  -4136  432  -1945  610  1035  -1090  2752  -558  1431  -2320  -1016  789  5084  -2395  -2916  -225  -311  -703  586  1110  -557  -1152  1096  229  425  5825  -933  3922  -6289  7423  -6636  -793  -2123  -354  991  -1947  3958  -1070  1380  -2120  -2777  -679  9010

Comment: See my answer to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10048755/273501

Comment: how did you solve these 000000000000 at the beginning of decoded frame? I am messing up with this particular problem currently.? thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0):

Speex is a lossy codec.  That means that the output from the decoder will usually be a little different than the input to the encoder.  Because Speex is allowed to change the data a little bit, it can compress the data more.

http://www.speex.org/docs/manual/speex-manual/node4.html#SECTION00413000000000000000

Comment: Thank you for replying.Do you mean that decoding back a frame will result in different one from the encoded?..to the degree of the major difference shown above (in the comments, BUFFER DECODED BACK)? is there a method to ensure that Speex works correctly?

Comment: Don't put your output in comments.  Edit your question and paste it in there, formatted as code.

Comment: i can't exceed max character limits!